# Removing muliple items from listview using Check box in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Hi i am stuck with deleting multiple items from listview using checkbox. I am able to select multiple items from listview but only the first item that is selected, is getting deleted while other items are not being deleted. Here is my code. Thanks in Advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    ListView lv;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    Button delete;
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        delete = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        data.add("Windows");
        data.add("Android");
        data.add("Apple");
        data.add("Blackberry");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, data);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                deleteCheckedItems();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    private void deleteCheckedItems() {
        int count = adapter.getCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
        {
            if (lv.isItemChecked(i))
            {
               data.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a SparseBooleanArray to get the checked items and then delete the same and refresh listview.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    ListView lv;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    Button delete;
    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        delete = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        data.add("Windows");
        data.add("Android");
        data.add("Apple");
        data.add("Blackberry");
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, data);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {

                SparseBooleanArray checked = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
                for (int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++){

                    if (checked.get(i)==true)
                    {
                         data.remove(i);

                    } 
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

                }
                 lv.clearChoices();               
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Edit:

Try the below

```
 delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

             SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
             int itemCount = lv.getCount();

             for(int i=itemCount-1; i >= 0; i--){
                 if(checkedItemPositions.get(i)){
                     adapter.remove(data.get(i));
                 }
             }
             checkedItemPositions.clear();
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks Raghunandan for your reply..but its not deleting the selected items..if i select two items..it deletes which i selected first and next item of that

Comment: @Giridharan it works fine i tested it just now. i don't see a problem

Comment: @Raghunanadan:Logic is not working fine for me..am using your logic only raghu..:(

Comment: @Giridharan will cross check again

Comment: @Raghunanadan:Have u checked??

Comment: @Giridharan yes i checked the problem is refereshing the lsitview after deletion. try logging `data.get(i)` in  `if (checked.get(i)==true)` . you get the checked items. so the problem is refershing lsitview

Comment: ya refreshing list is prob..i tried with data.get(i) too its not working

Comment: @Giridharan i found the solution. there are 2 mistakes we comitted. CHeck the edit. while we delete we need to clear the checked item position also.

Comment: @Giridharan the second mistake was we called `notifyDataSetChanged `inside the for loop. its raghunandan not raghunathan

Comment: @Raghunandan can u post the remove method of adapter class

Comment: @FunLove there is no remove method there is check box for row items and a button at the button of the list. WHen you check the check boxes and click the button at the bottom those checked items are deleted and listview refreshed

Answer (score 0):

Use `removeAll` for `data` and pass an array of elements to be deleted to the method. The reson is this:

for example you have 10 elements, after the 4th element deleted, all indexes 5-9 are moved to 4-8, thus your cycle is not correct because you use `old` indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {

       SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
       int itemCount = lv.getCount();

       for(int i=0; i <itemCount; i++){
           if(checkedItemPositions.get(i)){
               adapter.remove(data.get(i)); 
               --i;
           }
       }
       checkedItemPositions.clear();
       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try code below. The code is based on recurrency. 
After the "OnClick" event the Bremselected is called. The ListView is iterated until the "checked" checkbox is founded. Then item is removed and another time (there is recurrency) the Bremselected is called and the new iteration begins from scratch with the "size" decremented.

```
public void Bremselected(View v)
{
final int size=lv.getChildCount(); /// lv=(ListView) 

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    CheckBox mchb=(MCheckBox) lv.getChildAt(i);

        if(mchb.isChecked()){
            lv.removeViewAt(i);

            Bremselected(v);
            break;
        }

    }
```

}